# Received signal SIGSTOP on saving to iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

When I save a single datum to the iCloud, it works fine and when I need to save number of data to iCloud, I put the same code steps to save inside the `for` loop.

When I tried saving number of data to iCloud, the following signal is received and the app is hanging infinitely. The signal received area is in the below image.

[image: wait_trap]

and the crash area points at

[image: crash area]

How I can debug this crash? Can someone help me with explantion ASAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for that method says, *"Important: Do not call this method from your app’s main thread."*  The warning goes on to say that doing so **may** cause a deadlock.  It sounds as if that's the condition you have.

Comment: @Philip, thanks for your response. But, Im sure that I didn't put these methods inside any main queue.

Comment: I was going by the picture of the stack you posted that says, "com.apple.main-thread".

Comment: Also, I noted that the code structure works fine on iPad where its not executed inside the `for` loop, but not on iPhone(executed under `for` loop). Will there be any possible of deadlock due to the loop? Coz, when I run the same under debugger(going on step by step), it works fine, but its not when the debugger is switched off.

Comment: Possible.  Deadlocks are often about timing.  If you read the documentation I quoted, it does say "**can** trigger a deadlock" not that it **always** will.