# Objective c Thread 1 signal SIGSTOP app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, boost

I'm trying to track down an error that appears to be definitely a timing issue.  I have an application that uses a Universal Framework.  When the process is complete in the framework an NSNotification is sent back to the application.  We have recently added a third party framework to our framework.  Now, while the methods for the third party framework are being executed, as execution returns to our framework I receive the following error in the Console Output:

```
Assertion failed: (exclusive), function assert_locked, file ../dep/include/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp, line 51.
```

But I'm not sure that is the ultimate issue, because our framework continues to execute and the NSNotification is sent back to the application.  Right after the Notification is sent and execution returns to the calling method (or the method call) in our framework I see a warning on the executing thread.  Then, execution continues back to the original calling method and the warning goes away.

Here's the weird part.  If I step through the code very slowly, it might just work.  If I'm not slow enough I get the SIGSTOP and the code never returns to the UI.  If I'm too fast, I get a SIGABRT.

I've been trying to find the exact issue using Instuments.  [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529420/1735836) backed up my suspicion that this is a timing issue.  I think the boost assert_locked Assertion might have something to do with this.

My code is pretty boring but I know you want to see it, so here it is:

```
- (void)generateImageTemplates:(UIImage *)src
{
    int result = 0;
    cv::Mat image = *(cv::Mat*)[self cvMatFromUIImage:src];

    user = IEngine_InitUser();
    int userID=0;
    result = IEngine_AddFingerprintRAW(user, UNKNOWN, image.data, image.size().width, image.size().height);
    result = IEngine_RegisterUser(user, &userID);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InnovatricsComplete" object:self];
}
```

If you're wondering what result is, it's an error code.  So far these have all come back equal to 0.  Meaning no errors.  I'll work on handling these errors once I can get a successful return to the UI without crashing.

Control returns to the method call:

```
- (void)generateImageTemplates:(UIImage *)processedImage
{ 
    [self.captureCommand generateImageTemplates:processedImage];
}
```

Control returns to the method call in the application View Controller:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        [self clearPressed:self.clearButton];
    } else {
        [self.cameraVC generateImageTemplates:self.processedImage];
    }
}
```

Finally, the NSNotification callback code:

```
- (void)onInnovatricsComplete:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self.cameraVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.cameraVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.cameraVC removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

I warned you it was pretty boring!

I'm completely stumped!  Though I continue to surf the internet for clues, is there anybody out there who can help me resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Here are some screenshots (in reverse order):

[image: SIGABRT 2]

[image: SIGABRT 1]

[image: SIGSTOP Thread Switch]

[image: SIGSTOP Lock]

[image: Thread details]

Answer (score 2):

look at NSUinteger’s answer in [How to know where crash for postNotificationName:object:userInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523927/how-to-konw-where-crash-for-postnotificationnameobjectuserinfo)

the listener might be deallocated before it recieves the notification.

Comment: Too easy!  I ran Instruments and looked for Zombies and didn't find any.  Also, I do have this code in viewDidDisappear to dealloc all observers:  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

Comment: can you try implementing the same logic without using notificationCenter but delegates instead?  I want to see if your code is having issues with NSnotificationcenter

Comment: I spent all day yesterday and have come to the conclusion that it is either the third party tool's issue, or I am not implementing it correctly.  If I remove the last call to the third party tool, everything works perfectly.  Sorry for the confusion but I had no idea where the problem was occurring.  Still would like to know more about a SIGSTOP.

Comment: I'll give you an up vote for the postNotification answer though, because that is usually the cause of an NSNotification issue like this.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: lol you better delete that comment or some pervert will email!  :O